# Android service not restarting when debugging

Tags: android, android-service, android-lifecycle

As the title suggests, my `START_STICKY` Service (`android:stopWithTask="false"`) will not be restarted when I swipe my App out of the recent Apps list when I'm debugging in Android Studio 2 Beta 6. It works fine if I start the App from the launcher instead of the Debug button of Android Studio. Is this expected behaviour or should I fill a bug report? I could not find any information about service not restarting while debugging and just found out by chance. Want to save other developers the hassle, so I thought someone might find this question useful.

Comment: Haven't tested, but my best guess is that when the process is recreated after swiping it gets another PID, different compared to the one the debugger was attached at the first place.

Comment: @Onik That's what I thought too. However, the logcat output shows otherwise, no output from the service or the service being restarted, unless the application was started using the launcher, even while selecting no filter instead of current application for logcat.